# File not loading (--load) via command line SBCL

Tags: bash, common-lisp, sbcl

I have read this answer here that explains how to load a file and execute functions from the command line.

My goal is to create a script that runs multiple functions in a lisp file from the command line.

I tried this:

`sbcl --noinform --load ~/quicklisp/local-projects/foam/foam.lisp --eval '(progn (main) (cl-user::quit))'`

I get an error that `(main)` is not a function in CL-USER (obviously).

The `--load` switch doesnt seem to load the file.

Note - I have `(ql:quickload :foam)` inside my .sbclrc. So the package loads into sbcl first.

I also tried adding `(in-package :foam)` into the eval. Which didn't work.

Here is an example of what I want to accomplish:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

do-something
do-something
do-something

# Load package and run multiple functions
sbcl --noinform --load file.lisp --eval '(progn multiple functions here )'


do-something
do-something

# Load different package and run multiple functions
sbcl --noinform --load file2.lisp --eval '(progn multiple functions here )'
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `(foam::main)`?

Comment: You could write a `print` at the end of your file, to have a proof if it is loaded.

Comment: There is `(uiop:quit &optional exit-code)`.